# Regex output not consistent for searching a word anywhere in the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.9

I am using PyCharm with Python 3.9. The aim is to search entire word in a string.
Below mentioned code is not working properly, it's giving the search word, only if it's at the start of the string.

```py
cs_pattern = '\s?' + search_str +'\s?'

if re.match(cs_pattern,v_remaining_text) is not None:
    print("Found the word")
else:
    print("Word not found")

v_remaining_text = " Falcon Two Three Contact Tower Four Five"
```

Above mentioned code will work fine for `search_str = Falcon`, but not for `search_str = Tower`.

Question: How I can make it work for any word search in entire string? Above regex is working fine on regex101.com

Comment: 1. Use `search` instead of `match` and 2. use raw string and 3. `re.escape` for search string

Comment: Also, use `\b` (word break) instead of `\s` if you only want to match the whole word (e.g. not match `cat` inside `scatter`)

Comment: @anubhava, re.search didn't work, say for "CENTER ALBUQUERQUE FALCON FOUR FOUR JULIETT",  and search_str FALCON, it's ALCON is also true here. I need to search whole word exactly.

Comment: @Nick, same is the result (as mentioned in above comment) if I use \b instead of \s.

Comment: `re.search(r'\bFALCON\b', 'CENTER ALBUQUERQUE FALCON FOUR FOUR JULIETT')` will match `FALCON`; `re.search(r'\bALCON\b', 'CENTER ALBUQUERQUE FALCON FOUR FOUR JULIETT'))` will return `None`

Comment: It worked @Nick Thank you!